# How to fix NumberFormatException for input string "0.40"

Tags: java, numberformatexception

i am trying to convert string value to long for further processing but this error occurs everytime

```
13-Feb-2019 13:15:35.593 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-570] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() 
     java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.40"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
```

Comment: Parse it as `double`. Can `0.40` be stored as a `long`?

Comment: You have to show how are you trying to do that for somebody to be able to help you. @ernest_k is right, this is a floating point number so you have to parse it like that. Also, the best practice is usually to surround those parsing lines with try-catch block.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to store the value 0.4 in a `long`. Long doesn't support floating point values, so you have to use either float or double.

Exceptions like this one can be handled in your code using try and catch.